# Auto refresh JSON data on an set interval in React Native using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm working on a React Native app for a radio station which displays song & artist info from a JSON url. How can I get the info to update/fetch every minute or so? I've tried a few variations of using setInterval, but can't seem to get it to work in my functional component. I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to use setInterval with an async function..? Thanks in advance!

```
  const [track, setTrack] = useState({});

  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch(" my API url ");
    res
      .json()
      .then(res => setTrack(res.data[0].track.title))
      .catch(err => setErrors(err));
  }
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
  });
```

```
<Text>{track}</Text>
```

Comment: Where from you are trying to retrieve info? Have you thought about web sockets?

Comment: It's a json file on a server (Centova Cast) which gets updated each time the song changes. It does look like web sockets might be good for this.. Any resources/examples you could point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to request every N period of time after first component mount, like:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Component = () => {
    const [track, setTrack] = React.useState('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let repeat;

        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(" my API url ");
                const json = await res.json();

                setTrack(json.data[0].track.title);

                repeat = setTimeout(fetchData, 60000); // request again after a minute
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message)
            }
        }

        fetchData();

        return () => {
            if (repeat) {
                clearTimeout(repeat);
            }
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <Text>{track}</Text>
    );
};
```